# How to tell whether my ASP.NET app is 32bit in a 32bit IIS worker process

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I need to ensure that my ASP.NET MVC app:

- was built in 32-bit mode
- is running in an IIS worker process which is in 32-bit mode (i.e. it's on a 32-bit machine, or it's running in WOW64 on a 64-bit machine)

I need to check programmatically, as I'm on shared hosting (I can't fiddle with IIS).

I can check `Environment.Is64BitProcess` (or equivalently `IntPtr.Size == 4`), but I'm not sure if that's for my app or the worker process. I need to know bitness for both.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. A 64-bit IIS can't load a 32-bit application, or vice versa. If your application is built in x86 mode, and it runs, that should already tell you the IIS process is 32-bit. You can check this on your local machine. As for checking that your application was built in 32-bit mode, this is something you do, not your host. Do you really need to check at run-time? Can you not simply verify locally that it is built as x86 before uploading?

Comment: @hvd Actually 64bit IIS has an option to run 32-bit apps in Wow32 mode. As for my DLLs, yes I need to check at runtime hence my question.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. 64-bit IIS can use a 32-bit worker process to run 32-bit apps. 64-bit IIS worker processes cannot run 32-bit apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your own question, looking at:

> Environment.Is64BitProcess

is good enough.

Applications on IIS are hosted in worker processes, each worker process can either be 32 or 64bit. This is a setting on the application pool that corresponds to the process. So all apps in the process have the same bitness. Your app always uses the same bitness as it application pool worker process.

Comment: Do you mean that I can determine the bitness of the worker process, and thus *infer* the bitness of my assemblies? So, 1) if the app is running, and 2) if I can query `Environment.Is64BitProcess`, and 3) if it's `false`, then I can assume the worker process is 32-bit (and thus my app is running in 32-bit mode). And since a 32-bit worker process cannot run a 64-bit app, I can thus *infer* that my assemblies were in fact compiled in 32-bit mode?

Comment: @hbob - Yes, that's what I'm trying to say. You can test this locally on your workstation by checking for `Is64BitProcess` and then changing the setting on the IIS AppPool and check again.